# How to capture keyboard input in Blender using Python

Tags: python, blender

I am using blender 2.6 and I have written a script to do a common translation that I need for keyframing an animation. How can I trigger the function using a keyboard shortcut instead of repeatedly pressing a custom panel button?

I want something like onkeypress() but outside of the game engine.

It works in several directions so it would be useful to link to a combination of a button and an arrow key.

This is for aligning with background movie frames, frame by frame. So this is why I want a better solution than firing the scripts by clicking with the mouse.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

To assign a keyboard shortcut try an example from the Manipulator Menu addon -

```
wm = bpy.context.window_manager
km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View Generic', space_type='VIEW_3D')
kmi = km.keymap_items.new('wm.call_menu', 'SPACE', 'PRESS', ctrl=True)
kmi.properties.name = "VIEW3D_MT_ManipulatorMenu"
```

If you truly want to capture keyboard input while your script is in control then look at the answer to [This Question on blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3465/how-do-i-catch-keyboard-input-for-a-blender-plugin)